# Formal adjoint of the symmetric gradient operator; is there a good interpretation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

Some context: I am reading Strang's paper, *A Framework for Equilibrium Equations*. In it, he gives a simple example with beams and rods. I'm trying to reproduce his arguments for 2D linear elasticity. In the paper, he considers conservation equations of the form
\begin{equation}
A^Tw = f
\end{equation}
where here $w$ is the stress variable, related to strains $e$ by Hooke's Law, $w = \mathbb{E} e$.

In the case of linear elasticity, I know that the equilibrium equation is $\mathrm{div} w = f$. This defines the operator $A^T$ as divergence. Integration by parts tells us that then $A$ is $- \nabla$. However, Strang's framework considers the strain $e = -Au$. The problem is, the strain is not defined that way. As far as I am aware, strain is defined as the *symmetric* part of the displacement gradient, not the full gradient itself.

This has led me to my question. **What is the formal adjoint of the symmetric gradient operator?** Does it have a nice interpretation? Here's what I have so far. Suppose we have smooth functions, and since we are looking for the formal adjoint, let us disregard boundary terms stemming from integration by parts. Let $u = (u_1, u_2)$ be a vector valued function, and let $\tau$ be a matrix-valued function. Then

\begin{align}
  ({Au,}{\tau}) &= \left({-\frac{1}{2}\left( \nabla u + \nabla u^\top \right),}{\tau}\right)\\ 
  &= -\frac{1}{2}\left({\nabla u,}{\tau }\right) - \frac{1}{2} \left( \nabla u^\top , \tau \right)\\
  &= \frac{1}{2}\left({u,}{\mathrm{div} \tau }\right) + \mathrm{B.T.} + ??\\
  & \vdots \\
  &= \left(u, A^\top \tau\right).
\end{align}

My question arises in how to integrate by parts the term $(\nabla u^\top, \tau)$. I attempt to do so by writing things out component wise, i.e. $(\nabla u^\top, \tau) = \int \sum_{i,j} \partial u_j/\partial x_i \tau_{ij}$. Integrating by parts moves the derivative onto $\tau_{ij}$, but I don't get anywhere afterwards. Can someone provide some insight, and help me to understand why many mathematicians disregard the important *symmetric part* of the displacement gradient when talking about strain? Thank you in advance!